# StackOverflowException with class

Tags: c#, class

I have a problem with a class that I wrote. When I try to call it I get an exception. See the code below for more clarity.

I have the class:

```
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace People
{
class Person
{
    // Auto prop + field
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.Name; }
        private set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                throw new NoNullAllowedException("Name is mandatory");
            }
            else
            {
                this.Name = value;
            }
        }
    }

    // Auto prop + field
    public int Age
    {
        get { return this.Age; }
        private set
        {
            if (value <= 0 || value > 100)
            {
                throw new Exception("Age must be between 1 and 100");
            }
            else
            {
                this.Age = value;
            }
        }
    }

    // Auto prop + field
    public string Email
    {
        get { return this.Email; }
        private set { this.Email = value; }
    }

    // Constructor 1
    public Person(string name, int age, string email)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
        this.Email = email;
    }

    // Constructor 2
    public Person(string name, int age) : this(name,age,"")
    {
    }

    // Write to console
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name: {0} \nAge: {1} \nEmail: {2}" ,Name,Age,Email);
    }
}
}
```

And when I call this class:

```
Person someone = new Person("First Someone",51,"someone@gmail.com");
Console.WriteLine(someone);
```

I get:

> Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.

I can't see the problem.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your properties call themselves on getters.

Comment: You could read this:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aa288470(v=vs.71).aspx.  It explains properties in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you try to get or set any of the properties, say, `Name`, there is a code path that calls the setter of the same property:

```
public string Name
{
    get { return this.Name; } // <<<<====== HERE
    private set
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            throw new NoNullAllowedException("Name is mandatory");
        }
        else
        {
            this.Name = value; // <<<<==== HERE
        }
    }
}
```

`this.Name` means "call getter/setter of `Name` with the value of `value`". This creates infinite recursion, causing stack overflow.

To implement properties with conditions like that you need to define fields that store the actual data. A common approach is to make these fields private, and name them with the same name as the property, except the first letter should not be capitalized:

```
private string name; // <<<<==== Add this
public string Name
{
    get { return name; } // <<<<====== change
    private set
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            throw new NoNullAllowedException("Name is mandatory");
        }
        else
        {
            name = value; // <<<<==== change
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
get { return this.Name; }
```

to

```
get;
```

the same goes for the Age property.

This is because this.Name is using the get method you are overriding, thus creating the glorious StackOverflowException! If you need a field for name and age you have to create one yourself like:

```
private string name;
public string Name
{
    get { return this.name; }
    private set
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            throw new NoNullAllowedException("Name is mandatory");
        }
        else
        {
            this.name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you please explain, why this is helping, so the OP understands his error?